# I can't make a POST call from POSTMAN but can do manually- Django

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, postman

I can make a POST call from Django REST Framework built-in API but,[Here you can see that result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1DZv.png)
I can't make such call using POSTMAN [image: postman result]

And also in-tab extension of POSTMAN, its showing

> "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

I have logged in as admin also,but its not working in POSTMAN
**Can you tell whats wrong going**

Below is the Code

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = Snippet
                fields = ('title','code',)

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

*Views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from snippets.models import Snippet
from rest_framework import viewsets
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer


# Create your views here.
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all().order_by('title')
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your django view has CSRF protection. You need to post the CSRF header when you use postman. You can capture those headers using the postman interceptor or you can capture those headers with the chrome developer tools. Once done, make sure you have the following in postman headers tab

```
Cookie:  captured session cookie, others are not needed
X-CSRFToken: Captured token something like QRG6UOm1EsD6iGCk26ELms75ho392KZlxLZeS5aP4gFNrsdI4vRRIrklpraq
Referer: http://localhost:8080 (or your live server url)
```

Comment: I got it man , Thanks a lot @e4c5. I done it using Chrome developer tools, You can find it here, below is the image url so that anyone can see it https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0PkiqHHXm_tTEVPRmRISDVHQnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

You can sign out first, it should be ok.
Or you can open new incognito window where you will not be logged in.